# How to calculate the position difference between 2 values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Train_stations = [ "Perrache", "Ampere", "Bellecour", "Cordeliers", "Louis", "Massena" ]
```

I started this :

```
start_station = input("Where are you now?")

ending_station = input("Where would you like to go,")


final = range(start_station) - range(ending_station)

print(final)
```

It does not work because apparently I can not user range with this type of value..

Comment: John, what do you think your code accomplishes? You got a list with data that you do not use at all. You ask for two user inputs so you got two strings in the variables. The range function works with integer numbers  - read the API [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) - so I got not the slightest idea what `final` should become ... if you want to know how many stations are between one value and the other you could use the `index()` method to get where / if someting is contained in your list ...

Answer (score 2):

How to get the index-difference of things inside a list: use [the `index()` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) :

```
Train_stations = [ "Perrache", "Ampere", "Bellecour", "Cordeliers", "Louis", "Massena" ]

start_station = ""
ending_station = ""

while start_station not in Train_stations:
    print("Possible inputs: ", Train_stations)
    start_station = input("Where are you now?")

while ending_station not in Train_stations:
    print("Possible inputs: ", Train_stations)
    ending_station = input("Where would you like to go?")

idx_start = Train_stations.index(start_station)
idx_end = Train_stations.index(ending_station)

print("The stations are {} stations apart.".format ( abs(idx_start-idx_end)))
```

Output:

```
Possible inputs:  ['Perrache', 'Ampere', 'Bellecour', 'Cordeliers', 'Louis', 'Massena']
Where are you now?Ampere 
Possible inputs:  ['Perrache', 'Ampere', 'Bellecour', 'Cordeliers', 'Louis', 'Massena']
Where would you like to go?Perrache
The stations are 1 stations apart.
```

Comment: After reading your solution this seems more logical what OP was trying to accomplish, well done

Comment: Thank you guys! it's very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to get the distance between station `indexes` you can simply use `.index()` and take the `abs()` of the difference.

```
train_stations = [ "Perrache", "Ampere", "Bellecour", "Cordeliers", "Louis", "Massena" ]

start_station = input("Where are you now: ")
ending_station = input("Where would you like to go: ")

final = abs(train_stations.index(start_station) - train_stations.index(ending_station))
print(final)
# Perrache Bellecour = > 2
```

Comment: why did you edit your first attempt using dictionaries?  that one would have been good if the OP wanted real miles between cities and had supplied those.

Comment: @PatrickArtner ty, but after analyzing the input and what you stated it seemed this ouput  was more on *track* haha :)